# How to push file from SharePoint Online to on- premise FTP location?

Tags: push

I have to try to push a file from **SharePoint Online** to on-premise FTP location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Onine is part of Azure public cloud. Public cloud has its own network and if you are looking to connect to your organization private network FTP then below are the ways -
1. Use Micrsoft flow (can run on SP event or recurring), create file using MS. flow and push to the SFTP location if your SFTP is public and can be accessible over the internet.

2. Use Azure logic app and by using SFTP connector, push the file to on premise FTP location.

You can also try by using on-premise gateway connector. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I have required both side full control??